# Can not override theme of Chakra UI in NUXT js using extendTheme

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, chakra-ui

Update 1

I tried the following as @kissu said but it didn't worked,
1.Adding the key directly in nuxt.config.js is not working :

```
chakra: {
    extendTheme: {
        breakpoints: ['89rem', '86rem', '90rem', '120rem', '200rem', '300rem'],
    }
},
```

2. Theme provider looks like this

> ```
> <template>
>   <div class="container">
>     <CThemeProvider>
>       <CColorModeProvider>
>         <CBox font-family="body" as="main">
>             <CReset />
>             <siteHeader/>
>             <nuxt />
>             <siteFooter/>
>         </CBox>
>       </CColorModeProvider>
>     </CThemeProvider>
>   </div>
> </template>
> <script>
> import {
>   CThemeProvider,
>   CColorModeProvider,
>   CReset,
>   CBox
> } from '@chakra-ui/vue'
> ```

3.I tried applying classes corresponding to the breakpoints and also a custom color but it didn't helped too

```
<CBox bg="mpw.50" height="2rem" width="2rem">sadsad</CBox>
<CBox as="ul" list-style="none"  d="flex" flexDirection="column">
<CBox as="li" list-style="none" borderBottom="2px solid #E8E8E8">
<CBox 
   :bg="[
   'rebeccapurple','blue','yellow','orange','grey','#8B008B','#7FFF00'
   ]"                            
   padding="1rem"  d="flex" v-bind="mainStyles[colorMode]">
<CImage :src="require('@/assets/imgs/patient.png')" w="5rem" h="5rem" alt=""/>
<CBox flex="1 1 0" padding="1rem" paddingTop="0" paddingBottom="0" v-bind="mainStyles[colorMode]">
<CText fontSize="2xl"  >
   Home Isolation Patients
</CText>
<CText pr="0.5rem">
   Lorem ipsum xyzzzz
</CText>
```

**anything else that I should try now  ?**

**Original Post is below**

I am unable to extendTheme in Chakra UI in my NUXT JS app. I want to use my own breakpoints as per my designs, which means that I need to have more than 4 breakpoints in my app.

In my `nuxt.config.js` I am importing it and using like below :

```js
import customTheme from './customTheme/custom-theme.js'

chakra: {
  extendTheme : customTheme
},
```

The file `custom-theme.js`

```js
console.log("LOADING CUSTOM THEME")
export default {
  // '38rem', '48rem', '62rem', '80rem',
  breakpoints:[ '89rem','86rem','90rem','120rem','200rem','300rem'],
  colors:{
    mpw:{
      50:"#EBEBEB",
    }
  }
}
```

When I do console.log in my index.vue

```js
mounted() {
  if(process.server){
    console.log("ON SERVER")
    console.log(this)
  }

  if(process.client){
    console.log("ON CLIENT")
    console.dir(this.$chakra.theme)      
  }

},
```

then I don't see my custom breakpoints

[image]

How can I add my own set of breakpoints like those breakpoints:`['89rem', '86rem', '90rem', '120rem', '200rem', '300rem']` ?

Comment: Did you properly setup the theme provider? Also, what if you try to directly set the keys rather than using a `customTheme` file? Also, try the classes on the template and see if it works or if you do have an error somewhere.

Comment: @kissu Adding the key directly is not working
`chakra: {
    extendTheme : {
      breakpoints:[ '89rem','86rem','90rem','120rem','200rem','300rem'],
    }
  },
`

Comment: I am doing this in the template 
`<template>
  <div class="container">
    <CThemeProvider>
      <CColorModeProvider>
        <CBox font-family="body" as="main">
            <CReset />
            <siteHeader/>
            <nuxt />
            <siteFooter/>
        </CBox>
      </CColorModeProvider>
    </CThemeProvider>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import {
  CThemeProvider,
  CColorModeProvider,
  CReset,
  CBox
} from '@chakra-ui/vue'
`

Comment: I didn't get the last point of trying classes on the layouts. Can you tell me what exactly that means ? :) Thanks for responding !!

Comment: Hi, please do not post code in comments but rather **edit your question** please. Try to simply apply your classes to a `div` and see if it does have an effect whatsoever.

Comment: @kissu I tried it but still can't get it , sorry for commenting the code